# How to write a facet_wrap (ggplot2) within a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I have written a function to plot a bar graph. But when I get to facet wrap the '~' sign is making things difficult.

```
rf.funct <- function(dat, predictor, feature){
  ggplot(get(dat), aes(get(predictor), N)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    facet_wrap(get(~feature)) # this is where the problem is
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
facet_wrap((get(~feature))) # invalid first argument
facet_wrap(paste0("~ ", get(feature))) # object 'feature' not found
```

How do i make sure the '~' sign gets included with the function?

Comment: feature is a string or?

Comment: What happens if you remove `get` from your code?

Comment: `facet_wrap(paste("~", feature))`. And, as @JakeKaupp said, get rid of all the instances of `get`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to use `get`. You've passed the data frame into the function using the `dat` argument, so just feed `dat` to ggplot and it will have the data from within its environment.

```
rf.funct <- function(dat, predictor, feature) {
  ggplot(dat, aes_string(predictor, "N")) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    facet_wrap(feature)
}
```

The `predictor` and `feature` arguments should be entered as strings. Then you can use `aes_string` to specify the aesthetics. `facet_wrap` can now take a character vector directly, without need of a formula (as pointed out by @WeihuangWong).

Comment: In ggplot 2.1.0, the `facets` argument can be "either a formula or character vector. Use either a one sided formula, ‘~a + b’, or a character vector, ‘c("a", "b")’." So the `paste(...)` might be redundant if OP is using a more recent version of ggplot.

Comment: I was using get() because the function included some data.table code above the ggplot code. I understand that I don't need to use get() for the ggplot section, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @WeihuangWong. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem and the answers & comments on here helped me fix it. However, this post is about 6 years old now, and I think the most modern solution would be along these lines:

```
rf.funct <- function(dat, predictor, feature){
  ggplot(dat, aes({{predictor}}, N)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    facet_wrap(enquo(feature))
}
```

Comment: while I agree with you that this seems like the recommended pathway nowadays I'll admit  that I have trouble understanding how anyone would consider this an improvement in terms of readability or clarity.